# The correct way to compare time in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to compare time a and time b. My JavaScript looks like this

```
    var a ="02/08/2016 9:00 AM";
    var b ="02/08/2016 11:20 PM";

    if (b<a || b==a){
       alert("End time is before or same as Start time.");
    }
    else{
       alert("Start time is before End time.")
}
```

After I run this code, it tells me that "The end time is before or same as the start time"? I thought with the values of a and b that I set, it should the other way around?

Comment: The best way is using `Date` and its API `new Date("yourDate").getTime()`

Comment: You are comparing strings. Why don't use [a library](http://momentjs.com/)?

Comment: Do you mean just the time or the date and time?

Comment: Why not just the `b<=a` and eliminate the or?

Comment: @Liam comparing the whole thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to turn them into dates and compare the time. `getTime` is not needed if you are sure you are going to compare using `< <= >= >` operators but won't work with equality `== === != !==` operators so I think it's best to just go for `getTime`

This is a simple and quick way to do a comparison but i suggest you to check how dates work (also what's the best format for dates)

```
var a =new Date("02/08/2016 9:00 AM");
var b =new Date("02/08/2016 11:20 PM");

if (b.getTime()<=a.getTime()){
   alert("End time is before or same as Start time.");
}
else{
   alert("Start time is before End time.")
}
```

Comment: Or you could use `<=`??

Comment: It's a bad idea to use non-standard mm/dd/yyyy format (or is it dd/mm/yyyy?) because all engines might not recognize it.

Comment: @Liam yes, right, i just got the question's code and didn't think about it. Editing

Comment: @valepu Hi Valepu, your code works great. But what do you mean by suggesting me to check how dates work. Do you mean the code you have provided has border cases where the code perhaps won't work? Just wanna make sure. Thanks

Comment: No it's just for your general knowledge. You should check the question yours was marked as duplicate and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date